# Telegram bot can't send direct messages

Tags: bots, telegram, php-telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api, telegram-api

I am creating a Telegram bot using `pytelegrambotapi`. But when I test the code, my Telegram Bot always replies with quoting my input [like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QvvFm.png), I don't want it to quote my input message but send the message directly.

Also how can I get replies by just using simple `Hi` or `Hello` not `/hi` or `/hello`.

My Code:

```py
import telebot
import time
bot_token = ''

bot= telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Hi')

@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, 'Read my description')

while True:
    try:
        bot.polling()
    except Exception:
        time.sleep(10)
```

Comment: I’m guessing reply_to does that to indicate what message it’s replying to. Maybe try bot.send_message(message.chat.id, “Hi”) to reply to the channel instead of the message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I don't want it to quote my input message but send the message directly.

`bot.reply_to` replies to the message itself. If you wish to send a separate message, use `bot.send_message`. You'll need to pass the ID of the user you're wishing to send a message to. You can find this id on `message.chat.id` so you're sending the message to the same chat.

```py
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def send_welcome(message):

    # Reply to message
    bot.reply_to(message, 'This is a reply')

    # Send message to person
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'This is a seperate message')
```

---

> Also how can I get replies by just using simple Hi or Hello not /hi or /hello.

Instead off using a `message_handler` with a `commands=['help']` you can remove the parameter to catch each message not catched by any command message handler.

---

Example with above implemented:

```py
import telebot

bot_token = '12345'

bot = telebot.TeleBot(token=bot_token)


# Handle /help
@bot.message_handler(commands=['help'])
def send_welcome(message):

    # Reply to message
    bot.reply_to(message, 'This is a reply')

    # Send message to person
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'This is a seperate message')


# Handle normal messages
@bot.message_handler()
def send_normal(message):

    # Detect 'hi'
    if message.text == 'hi':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Reply on hi')

    # Detect 'help'
    if message.text == 'help':
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Reply on help')


bot.polling()
```

Visual result:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If i understood corectly:
cid = message.chat.id
bot.send_message(cid, "Hello")